# How to extract bytes from an int variable(hexadecimal value stored in int variable)?

Tags: c, hex, bitwise-operators

Im trying to extract 4 bytes from hexadecimal value stored in int variable.

My idea is to "push" wanted byte to the end by using right shift operator( >> ) and then use AND operator with 0xFF value to get only last 8 bits of value. Its working fine with number values(73 for example) but its not working with values a-f(3f for example). I have tried using different formats for printf, like %02x , and i have also tried changing the mask for AND operator to 0x000000FF.

```
int variable = 0x12cd34f4; 
char byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3; 

byte0 = (char)(variable & 0xFF);
byte1 = (char)((variable >> 8) & 0xFF);
byte2 = (char)((variable >> 16) & 0xFF);
byte3 = (char)((variable >> 24) & 0xFF);

printf("%x\n",byte0);// prints fffffff4 
printf("%x\n",byte1);// prints 34
printf("%x\n",byte2);//prints ffffffcd
printf("%x\n",byte3);//prints 12
```

I expected it to print **f4** for byte0, **34** for byte1, **cd** for byte2 and **12** for byte3, but actual output for byte0 is **fffffff4** and for byte2 **ffffffcd**. I dont understand why those F values are added, and how can i get rid of them.

Comment: Read about how negative values are stored using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: char seems to be signed and gets promoted to an int when you do `printf("%x\n",byte0);`. Try `unsigned char byte0, ...`

Comment: use `uint8_t`, it's in stdint.h instead of unsigned char/unsigned int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` can be signed or unsigned, that is system dependent (and, maybe, as well depending on compiler options).

In your case, it is obviously `signed`. Values between `0x80` and `0xFF` (and not only those starting from `0xA0`!) have bit #7 set and are interpreted as signed value (e. g., 0xFF is -1, 0xF0 is -16, etc.).

When extending them to `int` (that's what happens when calling `printf()`), they are sign-extended (that's what the `F`s come from) and thus retain their "interpreted value". `printf()`, however, is told to treat them as unsigned again, so the -16 is represented as `0xFFFFFFF0`.

Either use `unsigned char` resp. `uint8_t` or add `& 0xFF` when calling `printf()`.

Answer (score 2):

Just force *char* to be *unsigned* :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int variable = 0x12cd34f4; 
  unsigned char byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3; 

  byte0 = (char)(variable & 0xFF);
  byte1 = (char)((variable >> 8) & 0xFF);
  byte2 = (char)((variable >> 16) & 0xFF);
  byte3 = (char)((variable >> 24) & 0xFF);

  printf("%x\n",byte0);
  printf("%x\n",byte1);
  printf("%x\n",byte2);
  printf("%x\n",byte3);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
f4
34
cd
12
```

Note that the `& 0xFF` are useless when a char has 8 bits

Comment: I think it is also worth pointing out that after changing `byte0` etc. to `unsigned char`, the casts to `(char)` are somewhat useless. (In fact, according to the specification, if the value being converted is outside the range of `char`, the result of the conversion may be implementation defined if or an implementation-defined signal may be raised.) Better to either change the casts to `(unsigned char)` or omit them entirely.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `%x` format specifier, without any modifiers, on its own, is for the type `unsigned int`, which apparently on your system is 32-bits.

The most significant bits of the bytes `F4` and `CD` are 1. This is the sign bit, so it is sign-extended to the full 32-bits (hence the `FFFFFF`), which are printed out.

Observe that when you print them out as `%d`, you see the sign bit in play too:

```
-12
52
-51
18
```

To solve this, you can make the bytes of type `unsigned char`, do a bitwise and on each `printf` argument with `0xFF`, and use the *correct* format specifier for an `unsigned char` in hex, which is `%hhX`.

Answer (score 2):

Your byte variables are declared as `char`, which on most implementations is signed.  When you pass these values to `printf`, it doesn't know the exact type of what you pass in because it's a variadic function.  So the `char` arguments get **promoted** to `int`.  And because you have values which are negative, they get sign extended as part of the promotion.

Change the type of these variables to `unsigned char`.   When the positive values are then promoted to `int` there will be no sign extension.